# How do I resolve this sed error when I transfer the script from shell to Makefile?

Tags: sed, makefile

So I have this makefile rule :

```
header:
    rm -f ./include/temp.txt
    cat ./srcs/ft_*/ft_*.c | grep -E "^\w" | sed 's/$$/;/' | sed '/int main/d' | sed '/int\tmain' >> ./include/temp.txt
    awk '//; /# define/{while(getline<"header.h"){print}}' temp.txt >tmp
    mv tmp header.h
```

I am trying to create a lib project and I have a lot of functions in the ./srcs/ directory, each functions is stored in a ft_name_of_the_function directory. I want to have a Makefile rule that edit the header file of the lib (which is in ./include/ and called header.h) by adding each prototype.

This script was working as a shell executable but doesn't seem to work after I put this in the makefile. I can still tell the makefile to run a shell executable but I would like to understand. When I run `make header` it gives me this standard output :

```
rm -f ./include/temp.txt
cat ./srcs/ft_*/ft_*.c | grep -E "^\w" | sed 's/$/;/' | sed '/int main/d' | sed '/int\tmain' >> ./include/temp.txt
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 10: expression régulière d'adresse inachevée
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'header' failed
make: *** [header] Error 1
```

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sed command:

```
sed '/int\tmain'
```

is not formed properly. You need an optional address (or addresses) and an action. If you run this at the command line you get this:

```
$  sed '/int\tmain'
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated address regex
```

If you want it to be like the previous one:

```
sed '/int main/d'
```

but with a tab instead of a space, you probably want this:

```
sed '/int\tmain/d'
```

You can combine these by using `\s+` to match some whitespace:

```
sed '/int\s+main/d'
```

Comment: You're welcome. It happens to us all from time to time!

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out I did some other mistakes so in some case people are trying to do the same thing here is my final code :

> ```
> cp ./include/initlibft.h ./include/libft.h
> rm -f ./include/temp.txt
> cat ./srcs/ft_*/ft_*.c | grep -E "^\w" | sed 's/$/;/' | sed '/main(/d' >> ./include/temp.txt
> awk '//; /# define/{while(getline<"./include/temp.txt"){print}}' ./include/libft.h >tmp
> mv tmp ./include/libft.h
> ```